# Regular expression to remove anything but alphabets and '[single quote]

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I change this regular expression to remove everything from a string except alphabets and a '(single quote)?

```
pattern = /\b(ma?c)?([a-z]+)/ig;
```

1. this pattern removes unwanted spaces and capitalizes the first letter and turns the rest into lower case
2. By alphabets I mean English letters a-z.

Comment: What’s an alphabet? Like the Latin alphabet, the Greek alphabet, the Cyrillic alphabet?  Is this legacy 7-bit data, or is actually Unicode, which the web is now over 80% of?

Comment: What is your current regexp about? More specifically, how's the `\b(ma?c)?` related to your need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To *remove* characters, you'd need to use something that actually does that, like the string `replace` function (which can accept a regular expression as the "from" parameter).

Then you're just dealing with a normal application of a [*character class*](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10), which in JavaScript (and most other regular expression variants) is described using `[...]`, where `...` is what should be in the class. You'd use the `^` at the beginning to invert the meaning of the class:

In your case, it might be:

```
str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z']/g, "");
```

...which will replace *except* the English characters A-Z (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ), a-z (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz), and the single quote with nothing (e.g., remove it).

```js
let str = "This is a test with the numbers 123 and a '.";

console.log("before:", str);
str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z']/g, "");
console.log("after: ", str);
```

**However**, note that alphabetic characters not used in English will not be excepted, and there are a **lot** of those in the various languages used on the web (and even, perversely, in English, in "borrowed" words like "voilà" and "naïve").

You've said you're okay with just English A-Z, but for others coming to this: In environemnts supporting ES2018 and above's *Unicode property matching*, you could handle anything considered "alphabetic" by Unicode instead of just A-Z by using the `\p{Alpha}` property. The `\p` means "matching this Unicode property" (as usual, the lowercase version `\p` means "matching" and the uppercase version `\P` means "not matching") and the `{Alpha}` means "alphabetic":

```
str = str.replace(/[^\p{Alpha}']/gu, "");
```

(Note that, again, `\p{Alpha}` means "alphabetic" but because it's in a negated character class, we're excluding alphabetic characters.)

Note the `u` flag on that, to enable newer Unicode features. That handles the "voilà" and "naïve" examples too:

```js
let str = "This is a test with the numbers 123 and a ' and voilà and naïve.";

console.log("before:", str);
str = str.replace(/[^\p{Alpha}']/gu, "");
console.log("after: ", str);
```

Comment: The OP says **"except"**.  So, shouldn't it be `/[^A-Za-z']/g`?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: **Thank you!** I missed the word "except"! Fixed.

Comment: How to remove a single quote except the ones starting and ending a word e.g. for "what's that, 'large' or not", I want to remove first single quote but leaving the one in 'large' unchanged.

Comment: Works prefect. Thanks.